# Haskell random generator : chain generation of random values

Tags: haskell, random, chain

I need to generate 3 random values in a row, where the first one determines whether the last 2 ones will be calculated or not:

```
randomEnemy :: World -> World
randomEnemy world@(World{enemies=e, rndGen}) = doR0 (randomR (0, 10) rndGen)
    where
        doR0 (a, g) =
            if a <= 1
                then doR1 (randomR (-562, 562) g)
                else world
        doR1 (a, g) = doR2 (a, randomR (-288, 288) g)
        doR2 (a, (b, g))  = world { enemies = e ++ [Enemy (a,b) (0,0)],
                                    rndGen=g }
```

However this is not working and I do not know why. It should simply calculate a random value between 0 and 10 which determines whether or not a random enemy should be spawned, then if so it should calculate 2 more random numbers for the position, otherwise return the current game state unchanged.

Although if I change the first call to `doR0` to `doR1` it DOES work, which leaves me totally clueless..

If anyone could help me out on this it'd be much appreciated!

Best regards,
Skyfe.

EDIT: The errors it throws (sumarized):

```
No instance for (Ord a0) arising from a use of `DoR0`
The type variable `a0 is ambigious`
...
No instance for (Random a0) arising from a use of `RandomR`
The type variable `a0` is ambigious
```

Comment: This is the point that I would really, really recommend using the `MonadRandom` package.  Also, your code would be a lot more readable without 40 columns of whitespace before the `where`.

Comment: I think I know your problem.  You're returning the same world every single time in `doR0` if `a <= 1`, but you have a new StdGen you could update it with.  If I simply change the else clause to `world { rndGen=g }`, then it generates lots of enemies.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried this but it still throws an error. Even if I put: doR0 (a,g) = doR1 (randomR (-562, 562) g) it still throws an error while if I'd put that directly to the randomEnemy function it does NOT throw an error, but it does if I call it via doR0.

Comment: I assumed you had worked around the constraint error already.  If there's an error, always post it in your question instead of just saying "doesn't work".  The error you have is because the compiler only knows that you want to generate a random value that implements `Num` and `Ord`, but it doesn't know exactly which type to use.  Change it to `doR0 (randomR (0, 10 :: Int) rndGen`

Comment: Or you can add a type signature to `doR0` of `:: (Int, StdGen) -> World`

Comment: That seemed to fix it, thanks! I still do not get why this was required for R0 but not for R1 though, but got it working now anyway.

Comment: The reason is because the random values you generate in `doR1` and `doR2` are inserted into your `Enemy` type, which presumably has them specified as `Int`, so the compiler can infer those values have to be of type `Int` coming out of `randomR`.  The `a` you use in `doR0` doesn't have any additional constraints on it, just `Num`, `Ord`, and `Random`, so the compiler throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from GHC not being able to figure out what type `randomR (0, 10) rndGen` should return.  The only constraints you've placed on this value is that you need to be able to compare it to `1`, so it needs to satisfy the `Random`, `Num` and `Ord` typeclasses.  The other `doRN` work because the random values you're generating are being placed into a data structure that has concrete types specified, so the compiler can infer what type of value to return from the other uses of `randomR`.  You can fix this by specifying that it needs to return an `Int` in several places, the cleanest is by adding a type signature to `doR0` of `(Int, StdGen) -> World`, so now the compiler can infer that `randomR (0, 10) rndGen` returns a value of type `(Int, StdGen)` since it's consumed by `doR0`.